# Magento2.1 order comes notification

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, notification

When order comes, there is no notification to see in default magento.
Need to get notification when orders come in magento2.1

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 allows sending a copy of orders to an email besides the customer's email.

This can be done by going to

Store > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email > Send Order Email Copy To

Comment: Thanks, but i need send notification like push notification function

Comment: This isn't standard functionality this is for mobile and you would need 3rd party script

Comment: Could you please send me a free 3rd party?

Comment: There are not many 3rd party softwares that are free